# Bert Multi-lingual fine-tuning for multilabel classification

Tags: nlp, huggingface-transformers, multilabel-classification

I’m trying to make French email sentences multilabel classification with certain categories such as commitmemt, proposition, meeting, request, subjectif, etc. .

The first problem I faced is that I don’t have labeled sentences rather I have french emails as dataset). Based on this I found the BC3 dataset (English emails) which has sentences annotated with some of labels listed above. So I came up with this approah; **First finetune a bert multilingual on this BC3 dataset on multilabel classification task and then make a zero-shot transfert learning with the finetuned model (or simply use it in inference) on sentences of my French emails**. What do you think about this approach?

So I started by prepropcessing the BC3 dataset and obtain 848 sentences, each of them with their occurences annotations according to each categorty. On the image below, the last 5 columns represent the number of time each annotator labeled a sentence for a specific label.
[image]

**Are those 848 samples enough to fine tune a Bert multilingual model?**

I try to fine tune by representing category as on the image below.

[image]

With one epoch, BATCH_SIZE = 4, the loss function did’t converge, rather it oscillates between 0.79 and 0.34.

What kind of advices would you give the solve this kind of problem?

Thanks.

Comment: What I would do is to just run all your training data though a translation service (e.g. DeepL API is for free or using Reverso). But my gut feeling is that 800 samples for 5 different labels is not enough. Depending on your use case, you could also reverse it: Input is in French, translated to English and only the English sentence is infered by the model.

Comment: @JérômeBau, Thanks for the proposed approach consistinf of translating my french Corpus in English.  I'll alsi try to find a way of augmenting my 800 samples.